# Is there a way outside of Azure to use the Youtube API to upload a video from Azure blob storage public URL

Tags: .net, azure, google-api, youtube-api, azure-functions

Please correct me If I am wrong, but my initial thought was using an Azure function to upload a video to YouTube using Youtube API (using this code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) , but I realized that this approach isn't feasible. The YouTube Data API has two methods to access data, ApiKey and OAuth. The ApiKey method would be what we want for server-to-server communication, but it's only able to access public information (list public videos, playlists, etc). We cannot upload videos to an account using the ApiKey method. The OAuth method is what allows us to upload videos, but this is an "interactive" OAuth flow, meaning it requires an interactive user to provide credentials in a device/browser. An Azure Function is not an interactive process. The solution to this would be to use a Service Account, which is for server-to-server OAuth. But YouTube does not support service account.

I am not sure how to get over this blocker of having Google APIs in my function. I am wondering what are other approaches that I could take? Is there a simple way outside of Azure to use the Youtube API to upload a video from Azure blob storage public URL? Thank you.

Below is my Function, that contains the Youtube API sample code taken from here(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

Function1.cs:

````
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace YoutubeUploadFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
            var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");
            await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Hi Peter, the youtube API support server to server authentication. see the link below: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

Comment: @Thomas It mentions on here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication (last two lines) that it does not support service account.

Comment: @Thomas please have look at the sample  Youtube API code and my code, I think you will see what I am trying to say.

Comment: nah but it support server side, have you tried what s describe in the link ?

Comment: @Thomas I don’t think the link you gave helps with my problem. How would I change my code above to do that?

Comment: I mean this is exactly what you re trying to achieve: you generate client credentials from youtube dev portal, you acquire an accesstoken (from your code) to authenticate then you call the youtube api with this token.

Comment: @Thomas so how do I change the current code to fit that criteria? Can you please demonstrate?

Comment: Try following the documentation, they have samples in lots of different languages.

Comment: @Thomas no that documentation doesn’t help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#ServiceAccountCredential